# when I try to invoke MFP adapter from Android Emulator getting the below error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server, worklight-studio

when I try to invoke MFP adapter from Android Emulator getting the below error

Refused to connect to 'http://localhost:6015/mfp/api/adapters/Example/unprotected' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: Are you really trying the from the emulator? Emulator and Mobile browser simulator are different.

Comment: can you update your question with your HTML and adapter invoke method ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this meta tag from your index.html and run the app again, it should work

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

This tag will block the adapter call